# help with a bash or shell script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

so for whatever reason my mddhfs pool seems to come "unavailable". I wanted to create a shell script that i could just run periodically via cron to:

1. see if location is available - if so do nothing -- else
2. run the following commands so i can "reconnect" the pool.

   - sudo umount -l /storage
   - have it enter my pw
   - sudo mount -a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#! /bin/bash
if ! [ -e '/check/path' ]; then
    sudo umount -l /storage
    echo password | cmd # works only if cmd reads from stdin
    sudo mount -a
fi
```

---

```
chmod +x /path/to/script.sh
```

Comment: do i just save this as a .sh file? and then i can run it from cron right?

Comment: @Travis You also have to make the script executable if you want to call it directly.